# Negative lookbehind equivalent in DART?

Tags: regex, dart, negative-lookbehind

Is there any way to achieve the equivalent of a negative lookbehind in Dart regexp? I need to match a string that does not start and end with a specific set of characters.

I am unable to find a regex that does this without failing if the matched part is found at the beginning of the string. Negative lookbehinds seem to be the only answer, but Dart doesn't have one.

This is the regex that I would like to work, but it doesn't:

```
(?<!(Me\.)|[frFR])(text)(?!\w)
```

It would matched `.text` or `text=` but not `Me.text` or `FtextABC`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer lies here:

[javascript lookbehind mimic](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/mimic-lookbehind-javascript)

The thing is that DART regex has exactly the same power as Javascript regex. Much to lamentation of many, Javascript does not support lookbehinds. But that link *will* provide an answer.

Comment: I personally like the string reversal method followed by the standard lookahead.

Comment: @OP if the answer is useful to you, may you thumb it up (or better yet accept it)? If not, may you report why not?

Comment: Sorry, I was AFK until now. You definitely deserve upvote :)
I already knew the link you provided and i was hoping in some more straightforward solution :) (Yep, I'm lazy).  Nevertheless, you confirm my thoughts and I will have to code it the way you suggested.

Comment: No worries brother. All the best!

Answer (score 4):

For those who need lookbehind assertions in Dart RexExp, as of version [2.2.1-dev.1.0](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#221-dev10), Dart supports lookbehind assertions. So OP's RegExp works in Dart as it is written.

```
RegExp re = new RegExp(r"(?<!(Me\.)|[frFR])(text)(?!\w)");
List<String> tests = ['.text', 'text=', 'Me.text', 'FtextABC'];
for (String t in tests) {
  print('$t: ${re.hasMatch(t)}');
}

/*
prints: 
.text: true
text=: true
Me.text: false
FtextABC: false
*/
```